How to find the standard deviation of the area normalised gaussian.
I see tons of guides for how people have found the area under $e^{-x^2}$ in order to create the gaussian with area=1. However, the normal distribution gaussian uses a factor of 2 in places, since the standard deviation of $\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ is $\sqrt{2}$. I haven't found any satisfactory explanations for how people found what the standard deviation of the area-normalised gaussian was. I've tried doing it by hand and using online algebra calculators but their solutions are always self-referential (they assume the deviation fact in their working out).
My question:
How would one compute $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,dx$$
This is the variance, so it should = 1/2

$$\left(\int e^{-x^2}dx \right)^2 = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^r re^{-r^2},dr,d\theta = 2\pi \cdot 1/2 = \pi,.$$

i cant believe i made that typo hold on ill fix it

this was about finding variance not area

Use integration by parts to remove the $x^2$ term.

I just tried a different IBP method where it seperates into $x * xe^{-x^2}$, diff the left integrate the right with a u sub and then use the gaussian integral result for the final bit, is that what you meant?

is there some way to mark this reply as an answer?
